# Assign values via two subsequent masking operations in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have generated two different masks based on values:

```py
import torch

values = torch.tensor([0, 0.5, 0.99, 0.87])
saved_values = values + torch.tensor([0.1, -0.4, 0, 0.1])
result = torch.zeros_like(values)

mask1 = values > 0
mask2 = ~torch.greater(saved_values[mask1], values[mask1])
```

Now I have tested if I am able to grep the data with the help of the masks:

```py
>>> result[mask1][mask2]
tensor([0., 0.])
```

seems to work, so I used broadcasting for testing further:

```py
>>> result[:] = 5
>>> result[mask1][mask2]
tensor([5., 5.])
```

Seems to work also, So I tested finally the values with the masks:

```py
>>> values[mask1][mask2]
tensor([0.5000, 0.9900])
```

Seems to work as well, so I try to assign the values based on the masks:

```py
result = torch.zeros_like(values)
result[mask1][mask2] = values[mask1][mask2]
```

Doesn't throw an error so I assumed it works, checked twice:

```py
>>> result[mask1][mask2]
tensor([0., 0.])
>>> result
tensor([0., 0., 0., 0.])
```

It seems the values are not saved properly due to some reference issues.

How can I achieve the wanted behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are indexing twice, currently `mask2` operates only after `mask1` has been applied. Why not define `mask2` unmasked (*wrt* `mask1`)?

```
>>> mask = (values > 0)*(~torch.greater(saved_values, values))
```

That way you combine both masks and only require a single masking:

```
>>> result[mask] = values[mask]
tensor([0.0000, 0.5000, 0.9900, 0.0000])
```

---

In case you *can only* / *only want to* compute `mask2` after having masked the tensors with `mask1`, you are still able to construct the resulting mask by indexing with [`nonzero`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nonzero.html) indices:

```
>>> mask = torch.zeros_like(mask1)
>>> mask[mask1.nonzero()[:,0]] = mask2
```

A cleaner implementation uses [`torch.scatter_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.scatter_.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_):

```
>>> torch.zeros_like(mask1).scatter_(0, mask1.nonzero()[:,0], mask2)
```

Comment: Seems to be a good solution an works in my situation, but what if the second comparison needs to apply `mask1` before? I have sadly no real Situation in mind where this should necessary.

Comment: Good point, well actually I can think of two cases where you must mask twice: (i) `mask1` is reducing the size of the original data batch and you want to process elements in chunks; (ii) when computing `mask2` requires some operation that is undefined for unmasked "`mask1`" values... Anyway, I've provided an alternative solution in my answer above!